# Kivy size_hint (popup) decimal error

Tags: kivy, sizehint

I am fairly sure I have gone about screen-scaling incorrectly, but my approach is as follows:

I have a popup that displays information, whose height may change, dependant on the number of lines presented to the user. As I roughly know the height in pixels per line (due to knowing the font size), I have incremented `i` counting the `\n`'s in the message being presented. I then divided this by the `Window.height` to give me a percentage of the screen required to properly display the information.

I know this information is displayed properly, when I hard code in the value resulted from the following equation;

```
    TwoDecPoints = Decimal(10) ** -2
    popupScale = (Decimal(i) / Decimal(Window.height)).quantize(TwoDecPoints)
```

But when I apply the `popupScale` (nn.nn) to the `popup`'s `size_hint`;

```
    InformationScreen.ResultsPopup.size_hint = 0.95, popupScale
```

I receive this error;

```
    Popup.size_hint_y have an invalid format (got Decimal('0.25'))
```

This eludes me, because I have a 2 decimal number, `0.95` which it never complains about. I have attempted to use it as a string;

```
    InformationScreen.ResultsPopup.size_hint = 0.95, str(popupScale)
```

As well as using the original `popupScale` without `quantize`, and trimming the number;

```
    popupScale = (Decimal(i) / Decimal(Window.height))
    InformationScreen.ResultsPopup.size_hint = 0.95, str(popupScale)[:4]
```

Neither of which work.

I have looked around the documentation about size_hint, but could not find any relevant information to the data-type that `size_hint` requires. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size_hint` is a [ReferenceListProperty](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ReferenceListProperty), a tuple of `size_hint_x` and `size_hint_y`.
 `size_hint_x` (resp `size_hint_y`) is a [NumericProperty](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.NumericProperty) it takes a float or an int. So `float(popupScale)` should do it.

Edit: if that didn't help the exact exception is raised in this [line](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/properties.pyx#L564)